# Why can't I get my In-Page Analytics to work?

Tags: google-analytics

I don't understand it. All my statistics are working perfectly, **except** the In-Page Analytics. It just says:

> We found no clickthroughs for this page. Try adjusting the date range or select another page.

[image]

I looked on the web and only found this post on the [Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/analytics/RB6ZGKNVtlE/Qek0pSWTAbwJ), but it contains only complaints, no solutions.

Then I found this solution over at [aillum](http://www.aillum.com/blog/2010/10/google-in-page-analytics-%E2%80%93-no-pageviews-recorded-for-this-page/) that suggested that the issue with **URI Filters**. But I have no filters installed at all:

[image]

What else could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that when you view In-Page Analytics, it displays the current URL at the top left:

[image]

Google Analytics allows you to override that URL with a custom one when a user views your website. For the specifics, you can check out the question [How can I set a Page Title with Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322288/how-can-i-set-a-page-title-with-google-analytics)

You can simply check if this is the case, by looking at any other statistics. Does the same page show up there like this?

[image]

There's your problem.

---

As a side note, I encountered this issue through a TYPO3 extension (`rsgoogleanalytics`). When setting `plugin.tx_rsgoogleanalytics.registerTitle` to `title` or `rootline`, this causes the reported page title to be overridden.